# execute cygwin sort command from batch file

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to run the sort command from a batch file to take the lines from new.txt and output them into unique.txt

C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "sort -u new.txt > unique.txt"

This is not working

However, if I place new.txt into the home/Administrator directory and run the command in the terminal it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sort -u /home/Administrator/new.txt > unique.txt
```

batch file:

```
set PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe /usr/bin/u.sh
```

all good :)

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to mark you own answer as accepted if it works - worked for me :)

Comment: You can do: `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH;sort -u new.txt > unique.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it directly from cmd without using bash:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\sort -u new.txt > unique.txt
```